# Playing .mp4 from expansion file Android

Tags: java, android, apk-expansion-files

I am trying to play around with android expansion files and i am trying to package multiple videos and play them in the VideView in android. I followed all the instructions given by google and I know there are a few post about this and I followed them and I still got an error. I made sure I zipped the file without compression. So i am at a standstill. As you can see the code fails at APEZProvider.java:160.

My error is:

```
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147): Process: com.myzendev.tourpure, PID: 3147
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor com.myzendev.tourpure.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at com.myzendev.tourpure.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.APEZProvider.openAssetFile(APEZProvider.java:160)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1486)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1552)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:388)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1080)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:921)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:848)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:981)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:352)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:72)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:628)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:579)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:176)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1956)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-28 11:21:21.099: E/AndroidRuntime(3147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name=".ZipFileContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.myzendev.ZipFileContentProvider">
    </provider>
```

This is my code:

```
public class ZipFileContentProvider extends APEZProvider {

    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.myzendev.ZipFileContentProvider";

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return AUTHORITY;
    }

    public static Uri buildUri(String path) {
        StringBuilder contentPath = new StringBuilder("content://");

        contentPath.append(AUTHORITY);
        contentPath.append(File.separator);
        contentPath.append("new/");
        contentPath.append(path);

        return Uri.parse(contentPath.toString());
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoViewDay1);
Uri uri = ZipFileContentProvider.buildUri("corrosionvideo1.mp4");
vv.setVideoURI(uri);
vv.start();
```

Comment: Can you post the code at line 160 from the APEZProvider.java file?

Comment: Your error log indicates that `APEZProvider` is attempting to open a `null` reference.  Double check that your `contentPath` is correct.  Based on your code, your `contentPath` is `content://com.myzendev.ZipFileContentProvider/new/corrosionvideo1.mp4`.  Is this correct?

Comment: @CzarMatt Ya that is the path i trying to reach. From the tutorials i been following it should work this way and i am having no luck.

Comment: @tim687 it the return statement `return mAPKExtensionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(path);`

Comment: Well lesson learned. My obb file had version 0. I changed it to version 1 and it worked. Looks like it has to be any number higher than 0. Works!